# How do I select an option in this kind form?

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, firefox, windows-10

I'm trying to populate some values in a MS forms like [`this`](https://forms.office.com/Pages/DesignPage.aspx#FormId=DQSIkWdsW0yxEjajBLZtrQAAAAAAAAAAAAN__pxMC8NUN0c3Mjk3Wk1OUTJUQllPSFA4MThFRUFJMC4u&Preview=%7B%22PreviousTopView%22%3A%22None%22%7D&TopView=Preview) for testing, it went fine for input[type=text], I can just select it and use SendKeys() but where there are a list of options, like below image, which isn't a regular HTML select so I don't know how set an option there. How can I do that? I've tried this:

```
        IWebDriver driver; // assume assigned
        IWebElement ele = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[title='Select your answer']"));
        ele.FindElement(By.XPath("//span[text()='Bahamas']")).Click();
```

but that hangs the application.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Dropdowns can be handled with Select class

```
SelectElement oSelect = new SelectElement(driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[title='Select your answer']")));

oSelect.selectByText("Andorra");
```

or by index

```
//keep in mind that the index starts from 0, not from 1

    oSelect.SelectByIndex(3);
```

or by the Html value attribute

```
oSelect.SelectByValue("Andorra");
```

More about Select, Options can be found [here](https://www.toolsqa.com/selenium-webdriver/c-sharp/dropdown-multiple-select-operations-in-c/#:%7E:text=Select%20is%20a%20class%20that,with%20regular%20class%20creation%20syntax.)

Answer (score 0):

As it is not a `select` type tag you can not use, selenium `Select` methods like `byIndex`, `ByValue` etc. Best possible way to deal with such drop down is to use `JavaScriptExecutor`:

```
// Click on dropdown field so that options will be available for select. Note in few cases this step wont be necessary
   driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[title='Select your answer']")).Click();
   IJavaScriptExecutor executor = (IJavaScriptExecutor)driver;
//Click on option you want to select
executor.ExecuteScript("arguments[0].click();",driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//span[text()='Bahamas']")));
```